# cannot unzipp the stanford corenlp files

Tags: ubuntu, zip, stanford-nlp, unzip

i downloaded the stanford corenlp archive from [stanford corenlp full](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09.zip)

using uGet [image: downloading] it is full downloaded but when i try to extract it it shows me  **An error occurred while extracting files**
i tried to unzipped from the terminal and it doesn't work also

help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to be more specific about the error. Have you tried another program to unzip it? Have you tried re-downloading the file? The md5 I have for the file on my computer is: `5134febe18bdbd830f3e8d5aff024b19`. If this doesn't match, then perhaps you have a corrupted version of the file.